# Passing information from one viewcontroller to the next with storyboards

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I can't find any information on this with storyboards. I've seen some ways to do it with writing all the code out and I could do it that way but I'm trying to learn the storyboards right now so.... here I am.

I'm creating a form on my first view controller. Two UITextFields, Two UIButtons that I'm using as checkboxes, and a UIButton that I want to hook to a segue to ViewController number two. The problem I'm running into is I need that information from the first view controller to be sent to the second view controller because that's where the information is actually going to be used. I have no clue how to do this though and the more I think about it the more I'm beginning to think I'm doing this completely wrong and I need to just stop and ask for help ;)

[image: Screenshot of my storyboard]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configure the destination view controller of the segue in `prepareForSegue`:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourSegueID"]) {        
        MyViewController* vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        //configure view controller here
        vc.detailData = someObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't think that worked unless you were implementing custom segues. Thanks